# Svn problem with Kiln

Tags: svn, kiln

I'm new to kiln (never used it before)

Trying to upload code via netbeans

I get the following error.

http://my.jetscreenshot.com/5627/20110125-xea9-127kb

Repository moved temporarily to '/Auth/LogOn ReturnUrl=%2FRepo%2FRepositories%2FGroup%2Fbestprice4me'; please relocate

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards, J

Comment: I thought Kiln only worked with Mercurial - not SVN?

Answer (score 1):

Kiln only works with Mercurial, but you are attempting to use NetBeans' Subversion report to interact with it.  Thankfully, NetBeans actually has great Mercurial support.  Simply tell it you're trying to connect to a Mercurial repository, rather than a Subversion repository, and you should be good.